# How to use query filter data that starts with a character in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm working with a large set of data and Id like to use the query function in Google sheets to pull out data that starts with that starts with a certain character only.

Is there a query I can write that will get all lines starting with 404 and 403?

404D1X4K1V0R01IA

403D1X4K1V0RXXF1

404D1X4K1V0RXXFA

405DMAIN1V0R03IA

501DMAIN1V0RXXFA

505WE23232323232

505VSE20122014X1

30300U50VXSRCCCF

30430U50VXSRCBCF

3057UX63VXSRBBCX

Thank you!

I was able to create a filter for 401 but I'm not sure how to add additional criteria.

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=filter(A:A,regexmatch(A:A,"^(403|404)"))
```

***OR***

```js
=query(A:A,"where A matches '^(403|404).*'")
```

[image]

Comment: Woah, the second option worked!!! Thank you for your help with this, I've never seen that syntax before and I'm going to start using it!

Comment: Worth noting that there's also an explicit 'starts with' operator you could use in this context: =query(A:A,"where A starts with '403' or A starts with '404'",0)